# Discontinuities of a monotone function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a monotone function. Then

1. $F$ has no discontinuities.
2. $F$ has only finitely many discontinuities.
3. $F$ can have at most countably many discontinuities.
4. $F$ can have uncountably many discontinuities.

Which is the correct answer and why ?

Answer (score 1):

The answers is 3.

Wihout loss of any generality, suppose $f$ is increasing. Let $D$ be the set of discontinuities of $f$.

If $d\in D$, then$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow d-}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow d+}f(x)$ exists. Thus, for every point of discontinuity $d$ we asign an interval $I_d=(\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow d-}f(x),\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow d+}f(x))$. Notice that all this intervals are disjoint. Now, let $g:D \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ such that $g(d)=q_d$ for some $q_d\in\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore $g$ is injective because all the intervalls are disjoint, hence $\left\vert{D}\right\vert \leq \left\vert\mathbb{Q}\right\vert=\aleph_0$.

Comment: In order to show that the answer is (3), rather than (1) or (2), the OP should also construct a specific monotone function with a countably infinite set of discontinuities.  (For example, a step function will work.)